# Embedded maps in react

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, embedding

I embedded google maps into my React project. I have the API key and when I run my app I see the map come up with an error that says this page can't load google maps correctly (do you own this website). After googling I saw that I would need to enable billing for my account to be active with google maps. I this actually the case and if so is it free. I went to enable the account and it said I would accrue charges if the limit goes over. I am building this project just for fun so I do not want to be charged anything ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you can work with Google Maps in the development view it just gives you a warning in the console. You can set the map from the google dev platform to your localhost but you don't have to pay for it.